# Eclipse Use Maven to change the version of a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I heard it's possible to change the version of a project using Maven. 
I am talking about the tag `<version>1.1</version>` in the project "pom.xml" and all the pom file of all the sub project.

I want to do that because some project may have a lot of subproject and do it manually can be real losse of time.

I am using eclipse if any of you know if it's even possible and if it is, how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is why do you like to change that within Eclipse. Doesn't your release process the version already? So using maven-release-plugin for example?

Answer (score 7):

You can do that via the [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) via the following from the root of your project:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

This will change all the versions in your pom files also of all your childs.
It will left over some backup file. This can either being solved by using the following:

```
mvn versions:commit
```

or maybe even better by starting with this:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2-SNAPSHOT -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

Comment: Improvement suggestion: Since OP seems focussed on Eclipse, i.e. the IDE, maybe point out that this is a command line command, which needs to be run in the command line (and on the pro side is independent of the IDE) inside (if it provides a command line widget) or outside the IDE.

Comment: The problem in Eclipse is you could only do that via search/replace which likely replace some other things which you don't like to do so doing such task in IDE is simply error prone....

Comment: Oh I'm totally with you that this is the way to do it. I'm just suspecting that OP or someone asking the same question might not even be that familiar with command line operations. Some beginners just "know" the IDE view of things and might look for a place to add that command in the IDE settings. So the suggestion was just to point that out. I've upvoted anyway, but felt that for some beginners that might make it more clear (especially since the question specifically targets eclipse and this is an "outside of eclipse" solution, which is fine, but might not be clear to everyone)

Comment: For a more Eclipse-oriented answer, you can suggest the M2E plugin that [allows to run arbitrary Maven goals](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html#run-the-build) from the Eclipse IDE

Comment: Thanx for the answer, it's true that launching a mvn command throuhg the IDE is not ideal and favourable to error. Using the cmd in the project repo is probably way safer.

Answer (score 0):

In my activities, to change the version of a project Eclipse using Maven, in Eclipse menu: Run > Debug Configurations, exists this Maven Builder (see the picture above) that change version when the button run is clicked and the newVersion parameter is filled:

[image]